# Count all lines containing a string in a directory with grep

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, grep

I have a txt file, path to which is parsed as $1 and a string ($2).
Txt file contains columns Dir,Dest, and in each line, a number of lines at files in Dir containing string $2 should be outputted to Dest path.

My idea is something like this, but it doesn't seem to work and manual debugging can't solve the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f $1 ]
then
    tail -n +1 $1 | while IFS=, read -r col1 col2
    do
        if [ -d $col1]
        then
            grep -rn -c  “$2” $col1 * > $col2
        fi
    done
fi
```

Input from terminal is this one

```
./Script_1.sh /Users/andjela/Desktop/test.txt string
```

The input (test.txt) file is

```
Dir,Dest
/Users/andjela/Desktop/OS/dir1,/Users/andjela/Desktop/OS/rez1.txt
/Users/andjela/Desktop/OS/dir2,/Users/andjela/Desktop/OS/rez2.txt
```

And an example of expected file (Dest,/Users/andjela/Desktop/OS/rez1.txt) should be something like

```
file1.txt: 2 (num of lines)
file2.txt: 1
```

Comment: Can you provide the "actual results" and "expected results?

Comment: also provide a sample of the txt file

Comment: @EricBolinger I have edited the question, thank you for the notice

Comment: You say "count all _**appearances**_" but you're counting _lines_. If your target string appears multiple times on one line it will only be counted as `1` -- could you clarify, is that what you want?  Separately, I'd name `col1` and `col2` used in your _read_ something more meaningful… `read -r searchdir outfile`?

Comment: @StephenP Yes, you are right, the number of lines. Edited

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a couple things about your script:

- There was no space after `col1` in this test: `if [ -d $col1]`.
- There are "smart quotes" around `$2`.  (Probably an editor feature being
  too helpful.)
- The use of `*` to match all files applies to the current directory rather than the subdir.
- The [online shellcheck utility](https://www.shellcheck.net) has a few other recommendations.

So adjusting for those plus the advice from @stephen-p produces this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f "$1" ]
then
    tail -n +2 "$1" | while IFS=, read -r searchdir outfile
    do
        if [ -d "$searchdir" ]
        then
            (cd "$searchdir" && grep -rn -c "$2" *) > "$outfile"
            # alternate:
            # grep -rn -c "$2" $searchdir/* > $outfile
        fi
    done
fi
```

My preference is for the alternate use of grep because it preserves the path.  But that's just me...